# 500 Internal Server Error in magento 1.9 checkout/cart page

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout

I am getting 500 Internal Server Error in magento 1.9  while open cart page in magento 1.9. There are also

**Error in log file**

```
  Internal Server Error 500 
No response from subprocess ( (cpanel)): The subprocess reported error number 72057594037927935 when it ended. The process dumped a core file.
```

**.htaccess File**

```
               ############################################
                    ## uncomment these lines for CGI mode
                    ## make sure to specify the correct cgi php binary file name
                    ## it might be /cgi-bin/php-cgi

                    #    Action php5-cgi /cgi-bin/php5-cgi
                    #    AddHandler php5-cgi .php

                    ############################################
                    ## GoDaddy specific options

                    #   Options -MultiViews

                    ## you might also need to add this line to php.ini
                    ##     cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1
                    ## if it still doesn't work, rename php.ini to php5.ini

                    ############################################
                    ## this line is specific for 1and1 hosting

                        #AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
                        #AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .php

                    ############################################
                    ## default index file

                        DirectoryIndex index.php

                    <IfModule mod_php5.c>

                    ############################################
                    ## adjust memory limit

                        php_value memory_limit 512M
                        php_value max_execution_time 18000

                    ############################################
                    ## disable magic quotes for php request vars

                        php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off

                    ############################################
                    ## disable automatic session start
                    ## before autoload was initialized

                        php_flag session.auto_start off

                    ############################################
                    ## enable resulting html compression

                        #php_flag zlib.output_compression on

                    ###########################################
                    # disable user agent verification to not break multiple image upload

                        php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off

                    ###########################################
                    # turn off compatibility with PHP4 when dealing with objects

                        php_flag zend.ze1_compatibility_mode Off

                    </IfModule>

                    <IfModule mod_security.c>
                    ###########################################
                    # disable POST processing to not break multiple image upload

                        SecFilterEngine Off
                        SecFilterScanPOST Off
                    </IfModule>

                    <IfModule mod_deflate.c>

                    ############################################
                    ## enable apache served files compression
                    ## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#gzip

                        # Insert filter on all content
                        ###SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
                        # Insert filter on selected content types only
                        #AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript

                        # Netscape 4.x has some problems...
                        #BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html

                        # Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
                        #BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip

                        # MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
                        #BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

                        # Don't compress images
                        #SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary

                        # Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
                        #Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary

                    </IfModule>

                    <IfModule mod_ssl.c>

                    ############################################
                    ## make HTTPS env vars available for CGI mode

                        SSLOptions StdEnvVars

                    </IfModule>

                    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

                    ############################################
                    ## enable rewrites

                        Options +FollowSymLinks
                        RewriteEngine on

                    ############################################
                    ## you can put here your magento root folder
                    ## path relative to web root

                        #RewriteBase /magento/

                    ############################################
                    ## workaround for HTTP authorization
                    ## in CGI environment

                        RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

                    ############################################
                    ## always send 404 on missing files in these folders

                        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/

                    ############################################
                    ## never rewrite for existing files, directories and links

                        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
                        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
                        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

                    ############################################
                    ## rewrite everything else to index.php

                        RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

                    </IfModule>


                    ############################################
                    ## Prevent character encoding issues from server overrides
                    ## If you still have problems, use the second line instead

                        AddDefaultCharset Off
                        #AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

                    <IfModule mod_expires.c>

                    ############################################
                    ## Add default Expires header
                    ## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires

                        ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"

                    </IfModule>

                    ############################################
                    ## By default allow all access

                        Order allow,deny
                        Allow from all

                    ############################################
                    ## If running in cluster environment, uncomment this
                    ## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#etags

                        #FileETag none
```

Comment: Check the answer & give feedback ;)

Answer (score 0):

It smells like a **memory** issue

If your webserver is using that access file (for instance, if you have **Nginx** as webserver then htaccess files are not used) & 512M is the real `memory_limit` for PHP then you have some coding problem in **checkout/cart** request (maybe you are printing some heavy object, or maybe you have some 3rd party module?)